# Default value passed to JS function not being read by browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid, default-value, qunit

I'm testing some client-side code and I have the following fragment:

```
        <div class="onerow">
            Sign ID: <input type="text" name="signId" id="signId" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value: siteId"/>&nbsp;
            Width: <input type="text" name="width" id="width" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value: width"/>&nbsp;
            Height: <input type="text" name="height" id="height" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value: height"/>
            <input type="button" id="buttonsearch" value="Search" class="k-button" data-bind="events: {click: onSearchClick}"/>
        </div>
```

In my test file, I set some default value for the Site ID using jQuery:

```
QUnit.asyncTest("List sites with set ID", function() {
    expect(0);
    $("#signId").val(13568);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#buttonsearch").click();
        QUnit.start();
    }, 1000);
}
```

However, when the page loads, the function call that *should* contain "13586" is instead blank:

```
...[field]:signId
...[operator]:=
...[value]:
```

At this point, manually clicking the button has no effect, and to get the function working again I have to *delete the default value*, click the button, *input a value for Sign ID again* and then press the button.

Ideally, I would want it to work right away for testing purposes. How might I accomplish this?

**EDIT: **

In my main `.js` file, I only have the following in my `ready()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#user-menu").kendoMenu();
    kendo.bind($("#site-search"), siteSearchModel);

});
```

I was under the impression that binding to the actual site, in addition to the timeout in the test function, would be more than enough time for everything to get ready.

**Second Edit:**

Additionally, if I put a `console.log($("#siteId").val());` in my QUnit test function, the value is displayed correctly. What could be going on here?

Comment: Does QUnit run only after the DOM is loaded? Because it sounds like you're trying to modify the DOM before its in the ready state or specifically before you `#signId` has been parsed and is ready.

Comment: Is the code where you set an inital value a) called and b) called after the dom is ready? If you are calling it with out setting it up in a dom ready function you run the risk of the element not existing yet.

Comment: Please see my edit. I believe I do perform the test after everything should be ready.

Comment: Where is the HTML located? If it's in the `<div id="qunit-fixture"></div>` element then that HTML gets reset after each test to whatever the value was at page load (before Kendo bindings take place). And really, what you're doing in that "test" isn't really testing anything since you have no assertions... is that intentional? If this is setup for a later test, then it should go in a [`setup` callback on a QUnit module](http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.module/).

Comment: The HTML is located inside a different file, and there is only a `<div id="qunit"></div>` element for running the test, not a fixture. Aside from that, I realize that I did not include the assertions above, but that's trivial compared to having it simply output the data with a default value, which is what I'm having issues with.